# Replace clock battery on Dell Inspiron 8200?

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron

I have an old Dell Inspiron 8200 laptop.  Still mostly works, but the clock battery has died so everytime I power it on I need to go into the BIOS and set the proper clock time.  From what I've been able to tell, replacing this battery is non-trivial, but I haven't found a clear answer.

How do I replace the clock battery?  And how do I buy a replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is Dell's manual page on [replacing the "reserve battery" on the Inspiron 8200](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins8200/en/sm_en/resbatt.htm#1084976).

Here is a [model 2664E CMOS Battery (7.2V, 15MAH, 3 pin)](http://www.impactcomputers.com/2664e.html) for $35, does this look right? It would be nice if Dell's manual gave a part number or some kind of spec.

Comment: +1 i see you got there first :)

Comment: I always seem to find the answer after I ask someone else for help :)  Does the one I linked to look right?

Comment: yep, that looks quite right.